# Changing the value in Map

Tags: kotlin

I'm studying kotlin. Now I'm solving a problem: if there is a `key` in the `map`, then substract one, and if there is not, then put 10. I wrote the code, but maybe it can be simplified without using an intermediate variable?

```
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, String>()

    val value = map["key"]
    map["key"] = if (value != null) (value.toInt()-1).toString() else "10"
```

Comment: You said "add one" but you are doing "value.toInt()-1"?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a typo

Answer (score 3):

For Kotlin/JVM, you can use [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)), and use this really nice nullable chaining in the lambda:

```
map.compute("key") { _, value ->
    // value would be null if the key doesn't exist in the map
    // so we chain the null all the way until we get the final string
    value?.toInt()?.minus(1)?.toString() ?: "10"
}
```

Though I would also suggest that you use a `MutableMap<String, Int>` instead, to avoid all the intermediate `toInt` and `toString` mess. Then you can just do:

```
map.compute("key") { _, value ->
    value?.minus(1) ?: 10
}
```

If you want a strings map later on, just [`mapValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html).

Comment: In addition to avoiding the repetition of `map["key"]`, this answer has the benefit that it's _thread-safe_. The code in the question (and, as I write, in all the other answers) can do unexpected things if another thread changes the map in between reading and writing it, which can cause intermittent bugs that are really hard to track down. (You don't need to be using threads explicitly; coroutines, web servers, executors, &c use multiple threads.)

Comment: @gidds I don't think thread-safety is necessarily guaranteed? Whether this is thread safe would depend on the implementation of the `MutableMap` used.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this

```
map["key"] = map["key"]?.let{(it.toInt() - 1).toString()} ?: "10"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map.putIfAbsent` method.

Method description: if the specified key is not already associated with a value or is mapped to null associates it with the given value and returns
null, else returns the current value:

```
map.putIfAbsent("key","10")?.let{map["key"]=(it.toInt()-1).toString()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code seems good to me. If you really want to avoid an intermediate variable, just replace `value` with `map["key"]` everywhere.

Other ways to do the same thing can be:

```kotlin
map["key"] = map["key"]?.toInt()?.minus(1)?.toString() ?: "10"
OR
map["key"] = map["key"].let { if (it != null) (it.toInt() - 1).toString() else "10" }
```

But I feel that the original code looks more readable than these.
Btw if the map contains only numbers, you can simply use a `mutableMapOf<String, Int>` and avoid the `toInt()` and `toString()` calls. And if it doesn't always contain numbers, you might want to use `toIntOrNull()` instead of `toInt()`

Answer (score 0):

for a better performance i recommend using `fastutil`

add this to your pom file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastutil</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

then in case, there isn't any key your put 10 else you subtract 1

```
import it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.Object2IntOpenHashMap

    fun main() {
        val key = "key"
        val map = Object2IntOpenHashMap<String>()
        if (map.putIfAbsent(key, 10) > 0) map.addTo(key, -1)
    }
```